# Concatenating two images horizontally - results with one black image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've been working with tiffs and I want to use patches to work with the images..
I extracted two patches - their shape is (200, 200) for both of them.

Once I use `concatenated_img = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])`

it results with a concatenated image, with shape (200, 400) but the second image is just a black image (the right one for example).

before concatenating, it wasn't a black image ofcourse..

can you please help me?

```
patches1 = patchify(img1, (200, 200), step=200)
patches2 = patchify(img2, (200, 200), step=200)
for i in range(patches1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches1.shape[1]):
                single_patch_img1 = patches1[i, j, :, :]
                single_patch_img2 = patches2[i, j, :, :]
                concatenated_img = cv2.hconcat([single_patch_img1,single_patch_img2])
             
                tiff.imwrite(path, concatenated_img)
```

Comment: Post your code please in order for people to help you.

Comment: added the code,thanks

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `img1` and `img2` (`img1.dtype` and `img2.dtype`)?

Comment: both are uint16

Comment: what are the `.max()` of each? if the range is 0..255, you need to `.astype(np.uint8)` because imwrite is sensitive to the `dtype`

Comment: Thanks! I figured the problem - I had to normalize both images before concatenating them...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.hstack` from the numpy library instead.Like the following:

```
concatenated_img = np.hstack((single_patch_img1, single_patch_img2))
```

Comment: thanks, the answer was to normalize both images before concatenating